# Validating New Entry OR Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many

A component has_many texts.
I'm using nested attributes with the component Model to create texts.
I also have checkboxes to select previously created texts (many through)

For each component, I can only select one text.

How do I validate the component for the text?
It should see if there's a checkbox selected (in the previous texts) 
OR it should validate the creation of a new text (textarea min 5)

How do I do that?

Thanks!
- Vincent

Comment: If on component can have only one text then why has_many association instead of has_one ?

Comment: Right now I'm only using one text indeed but I want to have the option to use many (for future updates).

Answer (score 0):

From the Rails [validations documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence):

> If you want to be sure that an association is present, you'll need to test whether the associated object itself is present, and not the foreign key used to map the association.

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order, inverse_of: :line_items
  validates :order, presence: true
end
```

Whilst I don't think this is what you're looking for, it will definitely help you.

--

What I do think you need is a definition of what you can do:

- Validate the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` (new record)
- Validate the `association` (association data)

If you're wishing to validate the associated object *on create*, you'll be able to put the validations in the associated model, which would then pass any of them back into the current model:

```
#app/models/component.rb
class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :texts, inverse_of: :component
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :texts
end

#app/models/text.rb
class Text < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :component, inverse_of: :texts
   validates :param, presence: true
end
```

This would reject the `text` record if it didn't have the `param` set on create.

-

If you were loading a `text` object, and wished to validate an existing `text` is available etc - you'd want to use the following:

```
#app/models/component.rb
class Component < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :texts
   validates_associated :texts
end
```

This makes sure all the [associated](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated) `texts` are valid.